# Crystal Reports - side by side details from actual and last year, using UNION ALL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, union-all

I'm creating a report that shows in the details section the current and last year of sales.

The rows of the report have a structure like this:

```
Article |||| LastYearQty | LastYearPrice |||| ActualYearQty | ActualYearPrice
```

There are two parameters at the report, the StartDate and EndDate.

I created a view view_RowsDocs, that will replace the original table RowsDocs, with the aditional boolean field IsLastYear to filter each line, but i'm having some problems to filter the date, classifying the rows at the last year or at the actual year.

For example, with `StartDate 1-1-2014` `EndDate 28-4-2014`:

```
IsLastYear || Article || Qty || Price || Date
   1           A0001     12     13,12    12-2-2013
   0           A0001     13     13,11    12-7-2013
```

What can be the best way to update the IsLastYear field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fact that you are using a View to get this relation with the `IsLastYear` attribute might be screwing you up. This is because by using a view, you are actually hitting the base relation. Your logic that determines the `IsLastYear` attribute is doing something screwy.

Instead, consider using a temp table to instantiate the relation with the `IsLastYear` attribute:

```
select   
    ...
    ,[Date]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as [IsLastYear]
into #myTempTbl
from RowsDocs
```

If you are producing this dataset with a stored procedure, include a `DROP TABLE #myTempTbl` at the end of the sproc.

Comment: Along the lines of SQL, you can create a formula in Crystal Reports to compare the year in the date field to see if it matches the Current Year: year({DATE})=year(CurrentDate)